# Uninstalling pow on OS X Yosemite

Tags: dns, port, hosts, rack-pow

I installed and uninstalled pow (using uninstall.sh from HEAD of master) on OS X Yosemite, however I am still unable to resolve .dev top level domains. I have a `/etc/hosts` file with the following entry:

```
0.0.0.0 myapp.dev
```

however when I do a `curl -v mayapp.dev` I get the following output

```
* Rebuilt URL to: mayapp.dev
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying     127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to mayapp.dev port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to mayapp.dev port 80: Connection refused
```

This used to not be the case. In addition I am also using haproxy to route traffic from port 80 to non-restricted ports. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like you are resolving the domain.  You just can't connect to port 80.  Either the service isn't running , or there is a firewall in the way.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a an issue of the new version of node not having permission to accept incoming connections. One way to fix it is just to restart the system, then the permission box will come up and just press allow and it should be fixed.